# Вставить дополнительный код в файл

Tags: c++, c

Есть файл `tree.cpp`. Как сделать так, чтобы другой файл `modified_tree.cpp` состоял из содержимого этого файла, но с добавленным `return` выражением в конце функции `int* create_tree()`?

Скорее всего, нужен какой-то макрос для добавления строки, но не знаю какой. Необязательно по названию функции, можно хотя бы по номеру строки.

```
// file modified_tree.cpp

#include "tree.cpp"

INSERT_STRING(create_tree, "return 42") 

// file tree.cpp

// code ... 

int* create_tree() {
    // code ...
    // -> insert return here <-
}

// code ...
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109473/discussion-on-question-by-user394222-----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если, как вы сказали, файл tree.cpp никак изменять нельзя, то остается только сделать его полный клон за исключением функции которую вам нужно модифицировать. Потом исключить из сборки оригинальный tree.cpp и подменить его своим вариантом. Можно подменить объектный файл на этапе линковки.

Ну а в своей версии можно действовать как вам удобно. Например макросом, если вам нужно несколько вариантов:

```
// tree_template.cpp
int * create_tree(){
     return SUPER_PUPER_RETURN;
}

// tree_42.cpp
#define SUPER_PUPER_RETURN (42)
#include "tree_template.cpp"

// tree_null.cpp
#define SUPER_PUPER_RETURN (nullptr)
#include "tree_template.cpp"
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что если `tree.cpp` изменится, то это решение никак не подхватит это и придётся делать `tree_template.cpp` каждый раз заново

Comment: можно как-то это контролировать, например хеш хранить и сборку останавливать если не сходится

Comment: и если не сходится, то автоматически перекопировать? Звучит как то, что надо, есть системы какие-нибудь для этого или самому писать надо?

Comment: Готовых не знаю, хотя на гитхабе можно и черта лысого найти, но у вас и проблема не стандартная. Сейчас питон активно используется для всяких нестандартный извратов, а у него библиотека богатая, думаю хеш найдется.

Comment: @user394222 Ваш вопрос относится к возможностям системы сборки проекта.